# allocation of memory more than 8 KB for device driver in linux kernel space

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, driver

I wrote a code for the device driver in kernel space, I would like to allocate more than `8KB` by using `_get_free_pages(size, flags)`.

Can you please provide the solution to allocate large lower memory in kernel space? (NOTE: Contiguous and physical memory is required here)

Initially, I was able to allocate `4KB`, by changing the order it improved to `8KB`, but I would like to allocate more than that.

Comment: Can you try using alloc_pages_exact(). Please see https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/mm-api.html#c.alloc_pages_exact

Comment: Assuming you mean `__get_free_pages`, you seem to have the parameters the wrong way round above. The first parameter is the GFP flags (e.g. `GFP_KERNEL` and the second parameter is the allocation order (log to the base 2 of number of pages).

Comment: Do you mean MB rather than KB?